# How to automate the installation of python interpreter in any operating system

Tags: python, automation, pip

Suppose I have built a program that will only gona show a pop-up in python but I want to run that in a machine in which python or any libraries are not installed so I want to know how to automate the installation of python it's like if I run that file python will install automatically with the required libraries also.

Comment: Do you have permission to install Python on that machine? Also, what OS does the machine have?  In any case, you can do that by writing a shell script or bat script or 
alike depending on the operating system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script